# A possible typo in textbook Introduction to Set Theory by Karel Hrbacek and Thomas Jech

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I think that statement *(c)* possibly contains a typo.

> *(c)* $P$ is dense in $C$, i.e., for any $p,q \in P$ such that $p < q$, there is $c \in C$ with $p \prec c \prec q$.

From another textbook *Set Theory* by Thomas Jech, I have a definition:

> *A set $D \subset P$ is a dense subset if for all $a < b$ in P there exists a $d \in D$ such that $a < d < b$*.

Thus I think that statement *(c)* should be:

> *(c)* *$P$ is dense in $C$, i.e., for any $p,q \in C$ such that $p \prec q$, there is $c \in P$ with $p \prec c \prec q$*.

Here is a screenshot taken from textbook *Introduction to Set Theory* by Karel Hrbacek and Thomas Jech:
[image]

And Here is a screenshot taken from textbook *Set Theory* by Thomas Jech:
[image]

---

> Please verify my observation!

Comment: @fleablood No, I think it's a typo - it's not the $<$ vs. $\prec$, but rather HJ seem to have swapped $C$ and $P$ in part (c) of their definition (surely $P$ should be dense in $C$ if between any two $C$s there is a $P$ ...).

Comment: @fleablood As the authors wrote originally *(c) $P$ is dense in $C$, i.e., for any $p,q\in P$ such that $p<q$, there is $c\in C$ with $p\prec c \prec q$*, this statement is trivial since $P$ is itself dense. As a result, for any $p,q\in P$ such that $p<q$, there is $c\in P\subseteq C$ with $p< c < q$ and thus $p\prec c \prec q$.

Comment: Oh... right.... that is a severe typo!  That would imply that $\mathbb Z$ is dense in $\mathbb R$!... And I guess my comment comparing $\prec$ to $<$ is irrelevant by b).  Oh well, still, I think the use of $<$ instead of $\prec$ was intentional.  .... but not the point.

Comment: @fleablood I think that's covered in their point (b).

Comment: @NoahSchweber Is my adjusted version correct?

Comment: @LeAnhDung Yes, it is.

Comment: Thank you so much @NoahSchweber!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you are correct - that's a very unfortunate typo!

Note that what Hrbacek/Jech have written can't *possibly* be true - it's easy to show that uniqueness breaks down if we use his definition as written (for example, take $P=\mathbb{Q}$ and consider - besides $\mathbb{R}$ - the linear order $\mathbb{R}\cup\{?\}$, where $?$ is a direct predecessory of $\pi$).